# VB.Net - Program can't Edit HKEY_Local_Machine registry entry

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a similar problem, VB.Net - Program can't Edit HKEY_Local_Machine registry entry, that was listed, but the fix did not work for me. I am using Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to create a portable app that will work in Windows 7 Professional and Windows 10 Professional. The idea is to reset the last logged on person to either Blank or a different user. My colleagues and I have to logged into member computers with an elevated account to work on them, but the member does not pay attention and causes our account to get locked out. we are not allowed to use group policy to correct this problem, so I am trying to do it with my app. I can make changes via regedit, vbs and batch files, but I cannot seem to get my program in VB2017 to work. **I took off the preferred 32bit checkbox and tried running it as an administrator or a different user with administrative rights.** I get the same error . . . cannot write to the registry (HKEY_Local_Machine registry). Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click

    Dim regVersion64 As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey _
                                (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64).
                                OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI")
    If chkbClearEverything.Checked = True Then
        regVersion64.SetValue("LastLoggedOnDisplayName", "")
        regVersion64.SetValue("LastLoggedOnSAMUser", "")
        regVersion64.SetValue("LastLoggedOnUser", "")
    Else
        tbd1 = TBLogon.Text
        tbs1 = TBsam.Text
        tbu1 = TBllu.Text
        regVersion64.SetValue("LastLoggedOnDisplayName", tbd1)
        regVersion64.SetValue("LastLoggedOnSAMUser", tbs1)
        regVersion64.SetValue("LastLoggedOnUser", tbu1)
    End If
    Dim rvLastLoggedOnDisplayName As String = regVersion64.GetValue("LastLoggedOnDisplayName")
    Dim rvLastLoggedOnSANuser As String = regVersion64.GetValue("LastLoggedOnSAMUser")
    Dim rvLastLoggedOnUser As String = regVersion64.GetValue("LastLoggedOnUser")

    If Not rvLastLoggedOnDisplayName = "" Then
        TBLogon.Text = rvLastLoggedOnDisplayName
        tbd1 = rvLastLoggedOnDisplayName
    End If
    If Not rvLastLoggedOnSANuser = "" Then
        TBsam.Text = rvLastLoggedOnSANuser
        tbs1 = rvLastLoggedOnSANuser
    End If
    If Not rvLastLoggedOnUser = "" Then
        TBllu.Text = rvLastLoggedOnUser
        tbu1 = rvLastLoggedOnUser
    End If
    regVersion64.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running your app as admin? Can you edit the registry entry manually?  What exact errors do you get?

Comment: Please tell us the exact error message you're getting, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: I have ran the program in Admin mode. I also did the following: I took off the preferred 32bit checkbox and tried running it as an administrator or a different user with administrative rights. The Error states I do not have permissions to make the write, but I can do it via a batch file, VB Script, and Regedit.

Comment: Exact error is Exception Unhandled: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Cannot write to the registry key.'

Comment: Any help from anyone. Please

Comment: Sorry, did not see your response. For future reference you can type `@username` (without spaces) in your comment to notify a user that you've replied (for example: `@VisualVincent`).

Comment: Anyhow, as for your issue it appears that you need special privileges to edit those values. Likely it would require you to enable a certain process privilege _or_ launch your application as a different user. Both ways are a bit troublesome, so I'd recommend just starting an invisible `cmd.exe` instance from your application (lots of examples of that if you google) and change the values from that instead.